# Please let me know when I'm running low on close votes!

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, voting, vote-to-close

Could have sworn there used to be a heads-up when you got down to one vote, but it sure doesn't work that way now. Very frustrating, to sit there considering a question, finally decide to vote, only to find out that I've been out of votes for a while.

Ideally, this would work the same way as up/down and comment votes do: when I get below a threshold (5 sounds good to me), let me know how many votes remain each time I cast one...

[George Stocker suggested a change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38919/closing-question-dialog-box-makes-me-go-through-steps-even-when-i-have-no-more) that would also work to solve this: show the number of remaining votes on the close dialog itself. I like this idea, as it avoids creating more pop-ups while still providing the necessary information.

[image: Screenshot of completed UI]

Comment: There's a limit? Where is this written and what is it? I have only done it a handful of times on Superuser.com but never knew about this limit.

Comment: AFAIK, it's 12 - but i can't find a reference to back that up for some reason.

Comment: As generally speaking, the longer you spend on the site, the more reputation you have, Maybe a better solution would be something like, one close per 250 reputation :S ... As the site already must remember / keep a record of how many close votes you submit, I guess this would only have to be a quick query at the time of closing and could be easy(ish) to implement.

Comment: How many close votes does one have? I seem to have 23 left on SU, and I've already used a few this morning.

Comment: @alex: Perhaps it's been doubled on SU because there are so few high-rep users. It's 12 on SO just like it is on Meta.

Comment: The dialog now tells you if you've already voted too!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They finished this:

[image: Screenshot of close dialog indicating no close votes remain]

Comment: @shog9: nice edit

Comment: It also tells you if you've already voted now too.

Comment: I really appreciate these changes. Very helpful.

Answer (score 42):

I know what you're thinking. "*Did he close twelve questions or only eleven?*" Well, to tell you the truth, in all this excitement I kind of lost track myself. But being as this is Jon Skeet, the highest rep user in the world, and would blow your question clean off, you've got to ask yourself one question:

[image: Do I feel lucky? Well, do ya, punk?]

Comment: The question needed a little more wood from the east.

Comment: @voyager - I'm glad you went ahead and made my day.

Answer (score 7):

This is a good idea - perhaps there could be a small UI treatment that would give you a heads-up display as to how many votes you have for each "vote-able" action.  It could pop up on hover of any voting button kind of like how the up arrow and flag appear on comments.

Answer (score 4):

Just ran out for the first time today.

I didn't know it was coming until *after* I'd spent several minutes reading answers in some alleged duplicates in an effort to determine if the new question really *was* the same as a previous one. When, at last, I decided it was I voted to close and *then* got told I was done for the day.

Very frustrating.

Answer (score 2):

I think I've run out of close votes exactly once.

Is this really a serious problem? If so, perhaps you should be rethinking what you're closing and whether it's in line with Jeff's guidelines on what's allowed. For example, career questions are OK but yet some still close them automatically. Also there are questions like [First-time software contractor, building a system for a multi-site client; who should own the intellectual property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1325968/first-time-software-contractor-building-a-system-for-a-multi-site-client-who-sh). Jeff commented:

> this is programming related and
>   explicitly allowed – J[eff Atwood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood)♦
>   yesterday

Now I doubt Jeff would comment as such unless he expected a certain segment of the SO population to jump on their close buttons because there's no code snippet.

So are you simply closing questions you shouldn't?

Comment: These days, most of my votes go to help close duplicate or OT questions. I usually check the list of close-voted questions towards evening, and spend any votes i have left on those i agree with. I don't think i've ever gotten through the whole list... there are a *lot* of duplicates, and always a fair number of SF or SU questions as well. The big problem is, i tend to forget when the day "rolls over", so some evenings i'll end up blowing the next day's allotment of votes without realizing it.

Comment: Maybe I don't spend enough time on SO each day but I pretty much never find things I want to vote to close...

Answer (score -5):

Hmmm. I don't think this is valuable. The problematic assumption here is that some questions deserve to be closed more than others.

If you feel something should be closed then it should outright be closed and not given a reprieve because you have one vote left and something else might be closier(TM) later. The system rightfully should be first come first served, and if you're not 100% on it then I would suggest you shouldn't be voting to close it anyway. This is all part of the market forces dynamic of open/close questions I think.

I would further suggest that if you do happen to see something you feel requires urgent closing if you run out of votes then you could always flag it for mod attention.

Comment: When I run out of votes, there are always, *always*, questions that I would like to see closed. When I run out of up/down votes, there are still posts I would like to vote up or down. And when I run out of comment votes, there are still comments I would like to highlight. The limitations imposed by the system force me to think twice about *all* the votes I cast, and try to vote those I feel are *most* deserving. The warnings merely come in handy when I miscalculate or when I encounter an unusually large number of good/bad posts. Finally, see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/357