# If a question has been closed before, are now more than 5 votes needed to close it again?

Tags: support, vote-to-close

I was looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995113/strangest-language-feature) that has been closed and reopen a countless amount of times (I'm sure many of you are familiar with it), and I couldn't help but notice `close (1)`.

So I clicked it (not because I wanted to close it, I just wanted to look at the proposed close reason) and it said `12 votes remaining`:

[alt text http://img29.imageshack.us/img29/5200/12votesremaining.png](http://img29.imageshack.us/img29/5200/12votesremaining.png)

---

Is this a new feature? If yes what's the exact formula to calculate the amount of close votes needed?

(I hope this isn't a duplicate, I promise I searched and looked at the blog too)

Comment: This is a hidden feature request: Make it "You have ____ votes remaining".

Comment: No freehand circles == I see nothing!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it's related to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18005/please-let-me-know-when-im-running-low-on-close-votes). You only have 12 closing vote per day, and now, it is shown how many you have left in this box.

Answer (score 4):

That's the number of close votes **you** still have. Nothing to do with the 5 close votes per question limit.