# Change the wording for "X votes remaining"

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close

I propose to change the wording of [the new close votes count](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18005/please-let-me-know-when-im-running-low-on-close-votes) from **12 votes remaining** to **You have 12 votes left**, as [the former can be confused with the votes remaining in order for the post to be closed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39378/if-a-question-has-been-closed-before-are-now-more-than-5-votes-needed-to-close-i).

I feel kinda stupid right now and I'm sure many of you haven't mistaken it, but if I did then other people probably will (especially new users). The change has no downsides and takes only a few seconds to implement.

[alt text http://img29.imageshack.us/img29/5200/12votesremaining.png](http://img29.imageshack.us/img29/5200/12votesremaining.png)

Comment: Seems reasonable and increases clairity. I give it a Meta-Question Reducation Score of 5. (The number of questions on meta it will prevent from being asked)

Comment: @Chacha102: MQRSs?  I don't believe they exist.

Comment: @~quack: +1 for obscure Princess Bride reference.