# Why have I been seeing questions with 12 more votes needed to close?

Tags: support, vote-to-close

I've found when I vote to close I am told that there are 12 more votes needed to close. Why  would that be? I thought there was only one diamond or five regulars needed to close.

Screenshot:
[image: screenshot of close dialog]

Comment: screenshot or it never happened

Comment: Are you talking about delete? I've seen that on some highly voted community wikis.

Comment: @Jaun Manual - I've added a screenshot. @aaronsterling - no.

Comment: Your screen shot shows that you have 12 votes remaining. It does not say that 12 more votes are needed to close.

Comment: @aaronsterling - however then, when I click on it after voting, it seems to show 3 or 4 votes. Does that include up/down votes?

Comment: Screenshot doesn't at all match what you read in your head

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change the wording for "X votes remaining"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39383/change-the-wording-for-x-votes-remaining)

Comment: When you put quotation marks around something, people commonly expect that what's in the quotes is *literally* what you saw or heard. Quotation marks are powerful characters; please be more careful when you use them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That means you have 12 close votes left for that day. Questions only need 5 votes to close (or a binding moderator vote).

Comment: Hm, I can see why the question was asked. Perhaps changing the wording might make it a bit less ambiguous.